# A sum of a continuous random variable and a discrete random variable is a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $ X,Y $ be random variable such that $ X $ is continuous and $ Y $ is discrete.

Define $ Z=X+Y $.

I'm trying to prove that $ Z $ is continuous, but I cant really see why would it even be true. Any hints/ideas would be helpful.

Here's my proof:

In order for us to prove that $Z $ is a continious random variable, we want to show that $ F_z $, the CDF, is continious. We already know that $F_z $ is right continious, so its enough to show that its also left-continious.

Let $R_y $ be the range of the discrete variable $ Y $ and $f_Y $ be the density of $ y $ and $F_x $ the CDF of $ X $.

Now notice the following :
For any $t\in \mathbb{R} :

$ F_{z}\left(t\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(Z\leq t\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X+Y\leq t\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X\leq t-Y\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\left(X\leq t-Y\cap Y\in R_{y}\right)\uplus\left(X\leq t-Y\cap Y\notin R_{y}\right)\right) $

$ =\mathbb{P}\left(X\leq t-Y\cap Y\in R_{y}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\biguplus_{K\in R_{y}}\left(X\leq t-Y\cap Y=K\right)\right)=\sum_{k\in R_{y}}\mathbb{P}\left(X\leq t-Y\cap Y=k\right)=\sum_{k\in R_{y}}\mathbb{P}\left(X\leq t-Y|Y=k\right)\mathbb{P}\left(Y=k\right) $

$ =\sum_{k\in R_{y}}\mathbb{P}\left(X\leq t-k\right)\mathbb{P}\left(Y=k\right)=\sum_{k\in R_{y}}Fx\left(t-k\right)f_{Y}\left(k\right) $

All in all we have that for any $ t \in \mathbb{R} $ the following equality holds:

$ F_{z}\left(t\right)=\sum_{k\in R_{y}}Fx\left(t-k\right)f_{Y}\left(k\right) $

Now Im gonna use the following result from calculus:

let $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be a continious function such that both of the limits :

$ \lim_{x\to\infty}f\left(x\right)=a\in\mathbb{R} $

$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f\left(x\right)=b\in\mathbb{R} $

exists. then $ f $ is absolutly continious function.

The proof is pretty easy, for any $\varepsilon >0 $ there exists $x_1<x_2 \in \mathbb{R} $ such that for any $ x>x_2 $ it follows that $ |f\left(x\right)-a|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3} $

and for any $x<x_1 $ it follows that $ |f\left(x\right)-b|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3} $

Now in the interval $ [x_1-1,x_2+1] $, $ f $ is continious so by Heine-Cantor theorem there exists $0<\delta<\frac{1}{2}|x_{2}+1-\left(x_{1}-1\right)|$ such that for any $ s_1,s_2 \in [x_1-1,x_2+1] $ it follows that $ |f(s_1)-f(s_2)|<\varepsilon/3 $.

One can check that this $ \delta $ proves the absolute continuity of $ f $.

So, since $ F_x $ is such a function, ( $ F(\infty)=1 $ and $ F(-\infty)=0 $ )

We have that $ F_x $ is an absolutly continious function. So for fixed $ \varepsilon > 0 $  there exists $ \delta > 0 $ such that if $ |s-t|<\delta $ then $ |F_x(s)-F_x(t)|<\varepsilon $

Now fix some $ t_0 \in \mathbb{R} $ , we'll prove that $ F_z $ is left-continious at $ t_0 $.

Indeed for any $ t \in (t_0-\delta/2,t_0)  $ we have :

$ |F_{z}\left(t_{0}\right)-F_{z}\left(t_{0}-\frac{\delta}{2}\right)|\underset{F_{z}\thinspace\thinspace is\thinspace\thinspace increasing}{=}F_{z}\left(t_{0}\right)-F_{z}\left(t_{0}-\frac{\delta}{2}\right) $

$ =\sum_{k\in R_{y}}f_{y}\left(k\right)\left(F_{x}\left(t-k\right)-F_{x}\left(t-k-\frac{\delta}{2}\right)\right)\underset{F_{x}\thinspace is\thinspace\thinspace increasing}{=}\sum_{k\in R_{y}}f_{y}\left(k\right)|F_{x}\left(t-k\right)-F_{x}\left(t-k-\frac{\delta}{2}\right)| $

$ <\varepsilon\sum_{k\in R_{y}}f_{Y}\left(k\right)=\varepsilon $

Where I used the fact that CDF function is non-decreasing, and that $ \sum_{k\in R_{y}}f_{Y}\left(k\right)=1 $.

Im totally aware that there are much easier ways to prove it, but it requires additional tools that I do not have yet (I only know the definitions and the basic things that I used in my proof, also I saw other proofs that assumed differntiability and assume much less).

So by the way I noticed that any CDF function of a continious random variable is absolutly continious. Thats nice

Comment: Hint: $X$ takes values on some open subset of $\mathbb R$ which can be written as a countable union of disjoint open intervals (which may include $-\infty$ or $\infty$ as their endpoints). $Y$ takes at most countably many values. So what does the range of $X+Y$ look like?

Comment: @Math1000 I proved it and found out something nice, I'll edit my post now.

Comment: A very minor thing, but it is spelled "continuous." :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Define the PDFs of $X,Y,Z$ as $f_X(x),f_Y(y),f_Z(z)$. Start by proving that
$$
f_Z(z)=f_X(z)*f_Y(z)
$$
where $*$ denotes the convolution operator.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the measure of the set of possible values of a discrete variable is $0$ because it is countable. Can you proceed from here?